# Pandas: merging different sized dataframes and adding columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (`df`) that contains the company **name** and **country**, I have about 900 such lines.

| № | **Company** | **Country** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OAO1 | United States |
| 2 | OAA2 | Three |

In another dataset (`district`) I have the name of the **country** and its **location**, about 162 lines

| № | **Country** | **Location** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fiji | MULTIPOLYGON (((180 |
| 2 | Canada | POLYGON (((33 |

How can I merge these two datasets into one so that each company and its country will be associated to the location from the dataset district?

I need it for the future steps with geopandas.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: `df.merge(district, on="Country")` should work I think

Comment: Checkout this SO post for further information about `pd.merge`: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Try: `df.merge(district, on="Country", how="left")`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.merge(district, on="Country")
```